# WebRTC on Swift: Can't change audio settings

Tags: ios, swift, webrtc

I am using https://github.com/stasel/WebRTC to enable WebRTC support on Swift. I tried to change the audio settings using the following code:

```
        do {
            
            try RTCAudioSession.sharedInstance().lockForConfiguration()
            try RTCAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSession.Category.playAndRecord.rawValue)
            try RTCAudioSession.sharedInstance().setPreferredSampleRate(Double(96000))
            try RTCAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)
            try RTCAudioSession.sharedInstance().unlockForConfiguration()
        } catch let error {
            debugPrint(error)
        }
```

I have also tried using AVAudioSession instead of RTCAudioSession and no success.

Can you help me?